# Reading vocabulary file in Glove Implementation

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I have implemented glove model for BBCNews dataset following this code https://github.com/hans/glove.py
I have formed a corpus of a single file with single space between words.Vocabulary file got generated.Can you please explain to me how to read it?

[image: Text corpus]

[image: vocabulary]

Answer (score 0):

The vocabulary file should look something like this:

```
word1 word1_frequency
word1 word1_frequency
```

for example,

```
apple 102
are 10
```

and so on. Are you sure your model was trained correctly?

Source: Have worked with GloVe